# Как предотвратить у браузера переход на страницу? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

Есть такой код

```
<form asp-action="AddFile" asp-controller="Home" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" value="Текст для кнопки выбора файлов"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Текст для кнопки отправки на сервер" />
</form>
```

Его назначение - просто взять файл и отправить на сервер. Никуда переходить более не нужно, подразумевается что на страничке несколько таких форм и каждую нужно заполнить и нажать "Загрузить" и это не должно перезагружать страницу - а просто должно отправить файл.

На стороне сервера пробовал возвращать OK, пробовал ничего не возвращать - все равно браузер при нажатии кнопки загрузить закрывает текущее окно и открывает новое, с запросом. Запрос проходит успешно. Как сделать так, чтобы браузер делал этот запрос, но не открывал новое окно?

Код на стороне сервера(оба варианта)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task AddFile(IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {
     //Ничего не возвращаем
    }
```

Либо

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {
     return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Делайте это вручную, с помощью ajax.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А можно поподробнее? Как это именно сделать на Razor Pages? Что значит "вручную"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35783209/8324991

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться Vue(JavaScript-фреймворк). Для общения с API можно воспользоваться axios. https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html
К input прикручиваем обработчик v-on:change="file = $event.target.files[0]".
Данные переменной file можно через axios передать в контроллер.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios